# NON inverting Amplifier No Output in AC Input

Tags: amplifier

I have design a very simple non inverting amplifier using OP284 with single Supply Vcc (12V).
Input= 3.3V and 0V @ 1khz Square wave (From DAC Vcc 3.3V)
Output = 12V and 0V 1Khz Square Wave Ac Coupled
In between DAC and Non Inverting Amplifier is a voltage follower. Schematic is attached. Im using Double Opamp in one package. U9A and U8B are used in the same circuit in other chain. There are 2 channels that are identical.

Problem:

1. When both opamp has input, sometimes other amplifier does not have output (Means the amplifier is not Working no output). by just turning ON/Off 1 of the input signal.
2. I need the circuit to be robust by shorting Output(R150) should able to recover.
3. What particular specifications in OP284 that causes this failure. [image]

Open For better Circuit:

1. Add AC coupled at Non inverting Input Between Voltage follower and Amplifier with VCC/2 bias
2. Inverting Amplifier?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/585180/why-doesnt-this-non-inverting-amplifier-work-with-a-biased-signal-in-a-real-cir/585228#585228