# Analyzing an LM358 module circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, active-filter

I'm beginner in amplifiers and fiter circuits. I am working on a project that uses [an LM358 module.](https://protosupplies.com/product/lm358/)

Here is the schematic:

[image: schematic]

I have several questions

1. Is the schematic a two stage amplifier with first order lowpass filter? I found R2, R1, C1 configurated like a lowpass filter.
2. What are R3 and R8 used for? (red circle)
3. Why is C4 placed after R5? I think R5 should be series with R6.

Comment: (1) C4 is large (low impedance) so *kind-of yes* as the gain drops off from 10 going to HF. (2) for the same reason as R4 and R7. To bias the inputs to the midpoint between the rails. (3) C4 **is** in series with R6.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/585180/why-doesnt-this-non-inverting-amplifier-work-with-a-biased-signal-in-a-real-cir/585228#585228

Comment: You might want to treat that seller's 'specifications' with a coarse grain of salt. They state bandwidth is 700kHz which is optimistic by about 70:1. Even without the capacitors the bandwidth would be limited to about 50kHz because of the op-amps' gain bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, cascade-connected two amplifiers with low-pass filters. R1-C1 pair in the first stage, and R9-C3 pair in the second stage determine the -3dB (cut-off) frequency.

$$
f_C=\frac{1}{2\pi\ R \ C}=\frac{1}{2\pi 100k \ 100p}=15.9 \ \text{kHz}
$$

Both stages have the same components therefore same cut-off frequency, so the entire circuit will have a sharper cut at this frequency. See the Bode plot below (for reference only – Red: each stage, blue: total):

[image]

<sup>[ImgSrc](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/second-order-filters.html)</sup>

2. R3-R8 and R4-R7 pairs are for biasing (google virtual ground). Each stage is an inverting amplifier. Because the op-amp is supplied from a single source, the output will not be able to swing to negative voltages since the VEE is ground (0V). So if you apply your input to [an un-biased single-supply inverting amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Inverting_amplifier) you'll lose the negative portion of the signal. If you bias the output to a positive voltage properly the output will swing around this DC offset so you don't lose the negative swing:

[image]

Ideally, this offset should be half the supply voltage to allow equal headroom. I'll try to explain below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYd58h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- At DC (all the capacitors are open-circuit) the circuit turns into a buffer for a DC input of half the VCC i.e. by R3-R8 divider. So the output will be VCC/2.
- At AC (all the capacitors are back, the DC voltages are now 0V/ground), the non-inverting input of the op amp will be connected to ground through the parallel equivalent of R3-R8 pair. So the circuit forms an inverting amplifier.

The actual output will be the sum of these (remember superposition), so the total output will be the amplified signal but with an offset of VCC/2.

3. C4 removes the DC offset coming from the previous stage, otherwise that DC offset would be amplified by the next stage which would possibly result in signal clipping. C4 doesn't have to come before R6 i.e. it could come after R6. What matters is the function. The order of the placement might be meaningful for the assembly. But electrically, it is not.

Comment: thanks for replying, it is clearer for me, with your graph and schematic.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, two stage amplifier, both stages have lowpass. But the lowpass is just for keeping the amp stable, as each stage has 16 kHz lowpass. But on the other hand, the chips are not DC coupled so there is DC blocking caps that are high pass filters of 16 Hz.
2. The R3 and R8 make half-supply bias voltage, just like R4 and R7.
3. You can swap C4 and R6, or you could put C4 before R5, but then R5 would not be a DC load for output of first op-amp.  And the pot setting would affect the gain and frequency response slightly differently, as it would change the impedance seen by the capacitor. It is designed like this and there may be a benefit for R5 being a DC load for op-amp output.

Comment: Thanks for replying, 

1. Are DC blocking caps you mean C2 and C4 ?
2. Ok got it
3. OK, got it

Answer (score 0):

1. Each of the two amplifiers acts as a low pass filter with the output of the first amplifier being 0.707 of its dc gain (3 dB down) at fc = 1/(2 * pi * R1 * C1) and the second amplifier being 0.707 of its dc gain (3 dB down) at fc = 1/(2 * pi * R9 * C3). So, because each amplifier is 3 dB down at fc, the overall circuit is 0.707 * 0.707 = 0.5 or 6 dB down at fc. In practice the gain will be a little lower than this due to the natural roll-off with frequency of the op amp resulting from its GBW limitation.
2. R3 & R8 are used to bias the non-inverting input of IC1a up to half the supply voltage so that, under quiescent no signal conditions, the output of IC1a sits at half the supply voltage and there is then plenty of head room for an output signal to swing in either direction before the onset of clipping. R4 & R7 perform the same function for IC1b but these two resistors are not actually needed because IC1b can also be biased using R3 & R8 as in my circuit below. As you can see in my circuit below, I have added a 10 uF electrolytic across R8 which is required in order to filter out noise on the supply rail and prevent it from reaching the biased non-inverting inputs.
3. In my circuit below I have added dc blocking (ac coupling) capacitor C6 in order to ensure that there is only ac signal across the pot R5 and therefore the ac signal across the pot wiggles about 0 V. Without C6 there is dc across the pot which can cause an audible pot scratching sound through the speaker when the pot is adjusted. It is standard practice to include this capacitor. R5 is connected down to ground so that it creates a signal adjustment range of all of the signal down to none of the signal (pot gain of 1 to zero), if R5 was placed in series with R6 then it would not enable a 100% attenuation of the signal with the pot wound completely in-circuit. The maximum signal attenuation would be 1/2 (or -6 dB) with the minimum gain of the amplifier based around IC1b being 100k/(10k + 10k) compared with 100k/10k when the pot is wound completely out of the circuit.

[image: Amplifier]

If the input resistance to the circuit (R2) causes a problem by unreasonably loading the source then a more usual approach would be to use a non-inverting stage for the first stage so that you can have a much higher input resistance and therefore less loading of the source.

Comment: thanks for replying,
1. Ok so the circuit is same as second order Filter?
2. Ok, got it
3. so place C4 between Radjustgain (R5) and R6 is mandatory?